# Problema con tupla

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas, hemos realizado este método de algoritmos genéticos en Python 3 pero tenemos un problema de asignación a la tupla. Hemos leido que una solución podria ser convertir la tupla a lista pero no sabemos como hacerlo.

```
def selection_and_reproduction(poblacionNueva):

    #Puntua todos los elementos de la poblacion (poblacionNueva) y se queda con los mejores
    #guardandolos dentro de 'selected'.
    #Despues mezcla el material genetico de los elegidos para crear nuevos individuos y
    #llenar la poblacion (guardando tambien una copia de los individuos seleccionados sin
    #modificar).

    #Por ultimo muta a los individuos.


     puntuados = [ (calcularFitness(i), i) for i in poblacionNueva]
     def takeSecond(puntuados):
         return puntuados[1]
     puntuados = sorted(puntuados, key=takeSecond) 

     poblacionNueva = puntuados


     selected =  puntuados[(len(puntuados)-indAReproducir):]
     for i in range(len(poblacionNueva)-indAReproducir):
         punto = random.randint(1,largo-1) 
         padre = random.sample(selected, 2) 
         poblacionNueva[i][:punto] = padre[0][:punto] 
         poblacionNueva[i][punto:] = padre[1][punto:] 

     return poblacionNueva
```

El error que nos sale es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Carlos la respuesta de César soluciona el problema. Solo una observación por si te interesa; para ordenar usando el segundo item de la lista de forma eficiente puedes usar `operator.itemgetter` en vez de definir una función: importas  `from operator import itemgetter` y luego al ordenar simplemente haces `puntuados = sorted(puntuados, key=itemgetter(1))`. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo implementaremos.

Comment: @FJSevilla Genial, no lo conocía. ¿Es más eficiente incluso que pasarle un `lambda x: x[1]`?

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez es mas eficiente porque trabaja directamente a nivel de C a diferencia de `lambda` o funciones python normales.  Como referencia solo, acabo de hacer un pequeño test con una lista de 10 millones de tuplas y la diferencia al usar `sorted` es de 22.80 segundos de `lambda` frente a 11 segundos con `itemgetter`. Otra ventaja es que es serializable por lo que se pude usar `pickle` y se puede pasar como argumento a hilos/procesos a diferencia de `lambda`. Saludos.

Comment: @FJSevilla Genial, muchas gracias.

Comment: @FJSevilla Estoy viendo que `operator.itemgetter` es un tipo de dato, y `operator.itemgetter(1)` es un objeto de tipo `operator.itemgetter` y no un objeto de tipo `function`. Lo que pasa que como tiene implementado `__call__` es llamable.  No tenía ni idea. :)

Comment: Yo es que aún lo haría más simple ordenando primero: `puntuados = [ [calcularFitness(i), i] for i in sorted(poblacionNueva)]`

Answer (score 3):

Eso pasa porque las tuplas son **inmutables**, es decir, una vez definidas no puedes modificarlas. Actualmente tu variable `puntuados` es una lista de tuplas:

```
puntuados = [ (calcularFitness(i), i) for i in poblacionNueva]
```

Lo que puedes hacer, simplemente, es cambiarlo a una lista de listas:

```
puntuados = [ [calcularFitness(i), i] for i in poblacionNueva]
```